# how to compare or evaluate two different length strings characters by characters with redundant or missing characters in python?

Tags: python, string, nlp, levenshtein-distance

I want to mention the question again first, the comparison could not be from the head of two strings, and the lengths of two strings are not equal, so stop say this question is a duplicate question by something like `strcmp()` like I'm blind.

I'd like to do some kinds of evaluations for license plate recognition.
For a license plate like `ABD-3875`, I might get the result like 
`A80-3875`, `1A80-3875` or `ABB0-38B75`.
I want to know something like

`A80-3875`, `B` and `D` are wrong.

`1A80-3875`, `1` shouldn't be exist and `D` is wrong

`1ABB0-38B75`, 1, B B shouldn't be exist
the input should be two strings  like `ABD-3875`,`1A80-3875`
the output should be a boolean array : TFFTTTT
and a  int array to [-1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
-1 means the extra character is predicted 
0 means the location is correct but the character is wrong
1 means the character is correct
I know Levenshtein distance helps on this question, but since the long history of computer science, is there any particulate solution or even an opensource library for this question?

Comment: What is your intended input and output? Please format your question to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami is it ok now?

Comment: Arent you just looking for the argmax of the levenshtein distance

Comment: @RobinNicole I don't get it.shouldn't the levenshtein distance only be one for two strings?

Comment: No it gives you a distance between two strings. So it should increase as your strings get more similar

Comment: but for abcd and abc is 1 , abc and abcde is 2 abc and abc is 0
how can it increase?